# Some wrongs when i want to achieve search function in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, search

Here's my `models.py` (the models are being pulled from a MySQL database by django):

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models


class Cyshici(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    field_1 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb51', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_2 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb52', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_3 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb53', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_4 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb54', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_5 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb55', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_6 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb56', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_7 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb57', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_8 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb58', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_9 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb59', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_10 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb510', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_11 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb511', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_12 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb512', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_13 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb513', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_14 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb514', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_15 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb515', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_16 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb516', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_17 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb517', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_18 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb518', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_19 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb519', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_20 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb520', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_21 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb521', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_22 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb522', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_23 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb523', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_24 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb524', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_25 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb525', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_26 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb526', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_27 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb527', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'cyshici'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.field_1


class Shici(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    field_1 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb51', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_2 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb52', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_3 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb53', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_4 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb54', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_5 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb55', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_6 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb56', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_7 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb57', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_8 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb58', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_9 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb59', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_10 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb510', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'shici'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.field_1


class Shicibuchong(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    field_1 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb51', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_field = models.FloatField(db_column='\u6b21\u6570', blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    field_3 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb53', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_4 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb54', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_5 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb55', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_6 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb56', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_7 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb57', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_8 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb58', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_9 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb59', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_10 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb510', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_11 = models.CharField(db_column='\u5b57\u6bb511', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'shicibuchong'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.field_1


class Xuci(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    field_field = models.CharField(db_column='\u865a\u8bcd', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    field_1 = models.CharField(db_column='\u91ca\u4e491', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_2 = models.CharField(db_column='\u91ca\u4e492', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_3 = models.CharField(db_column='\u91ca\u4e493', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_4 = models.CharField(db_column='\u91ca\u4e494', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_5 = models.CharField(db_column='\u91ca\u4e495', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_6 = models.CharField(db_column='\u91ca\u4e496', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_7 = models.CharField(db_column='\u91ca\u4e497', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_8 = models.CharField(db_column='\u91ca\u4e498', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_9 = models.CharField(db_column='\u91ca\u4e499', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_10 = models.CharField(db_column='\u91ca\u4e4910', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    field_11 = models.CharField(db_column='\u91ca\u4e4911', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it started with '_'.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'xuci'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.field_1
```

Here's my `views.py` (I wrote search function here)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from dict.models import Cyshici

def index(request):
    Cyshici_list = Cyshici.objects.all()
    context_dict = {'cyshici': Cyshici_list}
    return render(request, 'dict/base.html', context_dict)

def search(request):

    result_cyshici_list = []

    if request.method == 'GET':
        if 'field_1' in request.GET:
            field_1 = request.GET['field_1']
            try:
                words = Cyshici.objects.filter(field_1=field_1)
                result_cyshici_list.append(words)
            except:
                pass

    return render(request, 'dict/search.html', {'result_cyshici_list': result_cyshici_list})
```

search.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8">
</head>
<body>

{{ result_cyshi_list }}

</body>
</html>
```

Here's my base.html. I want it to display the search form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf8">
</head>
<body>

    <form method="get" action="/dict/search/" enctype="mutipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
         <p><input class="form-control" id="search_cyshici" name="cyshici" /></p>
    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The HTML is returning a blank page. Can anyone help me understanding what's wrong or point me into the right direction?

Comment: your form should be post...

Comment: @aryan: the form can be get too

Comment: @aryan why need be post??? 'Get' isn't mean getting data ?

Comment: @dan-kiasson yes..so what do you thing the problem that i got

Comment: Looks like something went wrong with your automatic model generation. I doubt that those column name would work. You are not getting any errors?

Comment: @dan-klasson the models work and i am not getting any error. It just when i input data in the form and enter then nothing happen

Comment: Can you fetch data from the models? Are your column names in Chinese? What DB are you using?

Comment: In template you have `result_cyshi_list` but in view, you're passing `result_cyshici_list`

Comment: @GwynBleidD Yes thank you. I have changed it. But i got the blank square bracket. I think something wrong in my views.py. But i cannot figure it our..

Comment: Remove the try and except and maybe you get an error

Comment: Definitely something very_1 very_2 very_3 ... very_27 wrong with your model or is it something very_1 .. very_27 wrong with the existing table?

Comment: @e4c5 actually, i didn't want to create the new models and input the data again at the very start. I just want to get the data from Mysql's database when i use Django. But it seems that i have to create models when i use Django later, then i found i could use django to abstract models from my database.

Comment: @dan-klasson yes, and i change the code to 'result_cyshici_list.append(Cyshici.objects.filter(field_1=field_1))' Then i got a bracket also.

Comment: Can you show exact URL that you're requesting to get this data?

Comment: @GwynBleidD the url is '/dict/search'

Comment: so after form submission, there are any GET params in your URL? If no, try to remove enctype from your from (it doesn't make sense on GET), if yes, show them all here.

Comment: Remove this too `if 'field_1' in request.GET:`

Comment: @GwynBleidD I have removed the enctype. When i submit the form, i just got one brackets..

Comment: if you've removed try/except from your code and that array is still empty, there must be something wrong with conditions above. Debug values on them.

Comment: @GwynBleidD how to debug values?

Comment: Simply print them somehow, in console or in template.

Comment: @GwynBleidD yes. I followed your way. the variable words is empty

Comment: @GwynBleidD maybe something wrong in words = Cyshici.objects.filter(field_1=field_1)

Comment: That line is not evaluated. If it were evaluated you will get exception or non-empty list in template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form has only an input with the name 'cyshici', so this is the only key you'll get in your request.GET.
Try changing the input's name to 'field_1', or changing your view code to look for 'cyshici' key in request.GET instead.

Comment: yes! I have already noticed this problem and  I have changed this. But anyway, I really appreciate your help !!!!